# react-native-vector-icons not showing properly on android version 30-32

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, react-native-vector-icons

Why is my react-native-vector-icons not showing properly? This happens on SDK version 30 to 32, 33 is the only version that is working properly.

Below is the details of sdk version in my android project

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
...
}
```

package.json

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
"react": "18.2.0"
"react-native": "^0.69.1"
```

i tried this approach but still fails

app/build.gradle

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
    project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

I also tried various approach like downgrade the icons libraries, `./gradlew clean` and run android, but still nothing good comes up, anyone have ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "@expo/vector-icons" ,'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
or
You can also go to android/app/build.gradle
and add like this

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

then use command to manually link that like this

npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons

then check if  linking the react-native-vector-icons module to React Native done or not
May be in newer versions issue not remains anymore..

Comment: you mean i have to install these two? both under same libraries?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).